# How do I define the domain of a function?

Tags: plotting, functions

I have a function of two variables, `f[x_, y_]`, and I would like to restrict the domain to values of `x` and `y` greater than zero. How do I do this?

I also want to plot the function for restricted values. I have tried to use `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ...]`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: `f[x_?Positive, y_?Positive] := ...`

Comment: 3D plots, by the basic syntax of Plot3D, are restricted to a rectangular domain `x ∈ {x_min, x_max}` and `y ∈ {y_min, y_max}`. If doesn't work for you, please tell us what is the shape of the domain you have in mind.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use Boole ...  provided you are happy for your func to return 0 when the domain conditions are not met. For example:

```
f[x_, y_] := Boole[x > 0 && y > 0]  Cos[x] Sin[y] 

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 2}]
```

Alternatively, you can set up a Piecewise function with explicit settings for what is to be returned (e.g. Indeterminate) when your conditions are not satisfied.

Answer (score 5):

You may try "Putting constrains on patterns".

> *Mathematica* provides a general mechanism for specifying constraints on
>   patterns. All you need do is to put `/;` condition at the end of a
>   pattern to signify that it applies only when the specified condition
>   is True. You can read the operator `/;` as "slash-semi", "whenever" or
>   "provided that".

Example:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_ /; x < 4] := x + 1;
```

or

```
f[x_] := x + 1 /; x < 4
```

Result:

```
(* defined *)
f[3]
4
(* undefined *)
f[5]
f[5]
```

Note:

> In general, you can put `/;` condition at the end of any `:=` definition or
>   `:>` rule to tell *Mathematica* that the definition or rule applies only
>   when the specified condition holds. Note that `/;` conditions should not
>   usually be put at the end of `=` definitions or `->` rules, since they
>   will then be evaluated immediately.